# Can I save my Dieffenbachia from the cold?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

I moved my dieffenbachia to the house we're moving into, but its too cold. All the leaves are like a dark green and very very droopy. How can I save it?? Its almost 5 ft tall

Comment: Hey Kayle, please provide some pictures.